# C++ Autoclicker not exitising loop

Tags: c++, winapi

so I am trying to make an auto clicker that runs run you hold down the mouse button My current loop looks like  However when I run this it just clicks for ever and ever and does not stop when I release the mouse button. Thanks in advance. ps pressed is defaulted as false.

```
        while(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)&&!pressed)
    {
        pressed = true;
        INPUT    Input = { 0 };
        // left down 
       Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        ::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT
        // left up
        ::ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(INPUT));
        Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
        ::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT
        cout << "pressed"
        sleep_for(milliseconds(100));

        pressed = false;
    }
```

Comment: presumably the fact that you've sent a left click causes `GetAsyncKeyState` to return true

Comment: What in your loop makes it exit. You set `pressed` to true and then to false, not sure why you're doing that?

Comment: I was trying to get it to stop the second click from being registered but I didn't do it correctly is there anyway to ignore the click caused by the loop like another function other than ***GetAsyncKeyState*** @AlanBirtles

Comment: The return value of [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) is documented.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the return value of `GetAsyncKeyState` has two bits, we only need its highest bit, so we use `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)&0x8000`.

Secondly, the signal sent at the end of the loop simulates the operation of the mouse release, so the return value of `GetAsyncKeyState()` is 0, and you cannot continue to enter the loop to simulate the click operation of the mouse. Therefore, we should first simulate the mouse release operation, and then simulate the mouse click operation, so that the function can be realized normally.

Finally, `SendInput()` supports multiple operations at a time, we can build an array of INPUT, and then send the required signals at once, so that you can more easily achieve your needs.

Here is the code you can refer:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define INPUT_COUNT 2
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int pressed = false;
    while (true)
    {
        while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000)
        {
            pressed = true;
            INPUT Input[INPUT_COUNT] = { 0,0 };
            Input[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            Input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
            Input[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            Input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
            ::SendInput(INPUT_COUNT, Input, sizeof(INPUT));
            cout << "pressed" << endl;
            pressed = false;
            Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```